# iCarousel "cards" disappear when NSLayoutConstraint is applied

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, icarousel

I am currently working with iCarousel 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel on my project. The objective is to come up with a spotify cover flow UI.

I am facing problems with the following code:

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 350))
    tempView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    tempView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    tempView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tempView.backgroundColor = .white

    var uiimage = UIImageView()



    uiimage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "songAlbumCover")
    uiimage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    var temviewsmaller = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 350))
    temviewsmaller.backgroundColor = .yellow
    temviewsmaller.addSubview(uiimage)

    // When I included the following constraints the "cards" disappear why??
    uiimage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: temviewsmaller.topAnchor).isActive = true
    uiimage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: temviewsmaller.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    uiimage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: temviewsmaller.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    uiimage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: temviewsmaller.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true


    tempView.addSubview(temviewsmaller)
    return tempView
}
```

Is there a problem iCarousel and NSLayoutConstraint? I am trying to put more information on the "cards" such as label object and image object. But since I am not using storyboard and do everything programmatically. Been looking for online tutorial on this but no luck :(

Cards will show up correctly if no constraints are applied. But i need the constraints eventually since I am thinking of adding more subviews such as UILabel and such.

updated:

```
    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    print(carousel.contentView.center.y)
    print(carousel.contentView.center.x)

    let tempView = UIView()
    tempView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    tempView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    tempView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tempView.backgroundColor = .white

    var uiimage = UIImageView()



    uiimage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "yeezy")
    uiimage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    var temviewsmaller = UIView()
    temviewsmaller.backgroundColor = .yellow
    temviewsmaller.addSubview(uiimage)

    // When I included the following constraints the "cards" disappear why??
    uiimage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: temviewsmaller.topAnchor).isActive = true
    uiimage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: temviewsmaller.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    uiimage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: temviewsmaller.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    uiimage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: temviewsmaller.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    tempView.addSubview(temviewsmaller)

    temviewsmaller.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tempView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    temviewsmaller.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tempView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    temviewsmaller.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tempView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    temviewsmaller.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tempView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    carousel.contentView.addSubview(tempView)
    tempView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: carousel.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tempView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: carousel.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tempView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: carousel.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    tempView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: carousel.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true


    return carousel.contentView
}
```

Comment: @Mikent Sam  where are the constraints for tempviewSmaller?

Comment: @Mikent Sam you should better avoid using frames now and use constraints .

Comment: How can I avoid using frames to instantiate tempView? @TusharSharma

Comment: @Mikent Sam by using anchor constraints.

Comment: @TusharSharma i have updated the code above to use constraints instead of frames but it's still not working. Can you perhaps point it out where I am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: @TusharSharma *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'layer <CALayer: 0x600000033ee0> is a part of cycle in its layer tree'  this is the error i am getting